# Issues with indexOf in Javascript

Tags: javascript, indexof

I am having issues with indexOf in Javascript. It seems IndexOf fails to find a string when the it is obtained using .getValues() from a spreadsheet.

For example, the function below works fine.

```
function Narek() {

var array = ["Armine", "Narek", "Suren"]

var ggg = array.indexOf("Armine");

}
```

But this function, which gets the same names from the googlesheets returns -1.

```
function Narek() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("HL rota");
var array = ss.getRange(45,1,3,1).getValues();

var pickedHLM = ss.getRange(49,1,1,1).getValue();
var ggg = array.indexOf(pickedHLM);

Logger.log(pickedHLM)
Logger.log(ggg);
}
```

Any one can help?

Comment: please provide the inputs.

Comment: You can put console.log() after each line to test what values are you getting. You might have some null or undefined values.

Comment: @NaveenChandraTiwari. Thanks. I did put Logger.logs after each line and it correctly brings the array as well as the pickedHLM so there are no undefined items.

Comment: @DanielA.White what kind of inputs? My whole idea is to pick unique people names from the Array. It seems that I can't copy the whole code here (sorry, new to Stackoverflow and coding!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While **Range#getValue()** returns the top-left cell content (in this case the value inside A49), **#getValues()** returns a two-dimensional array of the cell contents of the whole range (ie A45:A47). Each inner array holds the row's values.

So perhaps more similar to:

```
var values = [["Armine"], ["Narek"], ["Suren"]];
```

This can be transformed into your expectation of a flat array.

```
var array = values.map(function(row) { return row[0]; });
// ["Armine", "Narek", "Suren"]
```

Comment: You are welcome @Sati, you can also 'accept' this answer to show the solution was satisfactory.